# Separate values in 1 field into x number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field called **multi_value** which contains this:

> "1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448"

I just need to separate each value into a field such as

multi_value1, 
multi_value2, 
multi_value3, 
multi_value4,
multi_value5,
multi_value6

**Things to consider:**

At times, it maybe only 3 values or it could be 2 values, but usually it will be a maximum of 6 values.

These values are currently separated by a comma as shown above.

The values can change in size from 2 characters all the way up to 10.

How can I achieve this using Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all the values numbers, and are they always separated by a comma AND A SPACE? If they are numbers and you are going to store them in a table, the column to store them should be of NUMBER type. ALSO: is it possible that you will have more than one such string? What do you do if you broke up one string, and then you get another one - now you will have two rows, both with multi_value1 and different values associated with them - is that OK? Splitting a string is not all that hard, but you must think about your requirements first - that is, ALL your requirements.

Comment: All values will be numbers and they will always be separated by a ', ' that is a comma and 1 space. So the field multi_value would read like this:

1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448

Obviously, it would be much easier if the end-user would simply separate all values into 6 separate fields, but they want those values to display in 1 field instead of 6.  

Can you illustrate the question?:   What do you do if you broke up one string, and then you get another one - now you will have two rows, both with multi_value1 and different values associated with them - is that OK?

Comment: Please take a look at the various solutions MT0 and I have provided (we each provided more than one solution, based on different interpretations of your requirement). See if any of those match what you need. If not, please explain again what exactly you need. For example, it seems in your comment you may want the OUTPUT to also be in one field - not sure what that means, I got a different impression from the original post.

Comment: I've taken a look at the queries below and Query 3 may work. I tried to create a Table in SQL Fiddle, but I get an error that I've sent to the admins to verify.

Basically, there is 1 field that has all those values separated by a comma and I am simply wanting to extract values (left to right) to place into 6 separate fields such as:

Output from Query 3.

Comment: You have the same kind of output in my answer, at the bottom. In a comment to my answer, I explain the differences between MT0's and my solution. One of them may work for you. Let us know if you need any changes.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @MTO  I ended up using your regexp_substr expression and it works great.  However, if the user places in a decimal, how can I account for that decimal to be shown?  For instance:  1700.45 should read in one field and not be separated into 2.

Comment: Instead of '\d+' you can use '\d*\.?\d+' - this will find all whole numbers and all decimal numbers (however, it will not find something like 12.  where there is no zero after the decimal point - if you have numbers like that, they can be accommodated, it's just a little more complicated). If you need to allow for possible minus sign, '-?\d*\.?\d+' will work. Again, if you also want to allow a PLUS sign, it's doable, just a little more complicated.

Comment: Is it possible, in your scenario, that you may have a string like '22, , , 33' meaning that multi_value1 = 22, multi_value4 = 33, while multi_value2 and multi_value3 are NULL?

Comment: @mathguy  You are the man!  I don't think minus signs will be coming into play here since everything should be positive.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I see what you mean by the sequence 22,,,,33...   I anticipate they will be putting those values from left to right and if they do not, then the will have to correct those data entries.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2_TABLE DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       VARCHAR2_TABLE := VARCHAR2_TABLE();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT split_string( '1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
MULTI_VALUE_STRING
---------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST.VARCHAR2_TABLE('1700',' 4000',' 3485',' 9684',' 20394',' 39448')
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( TRIM( COLUMN_VALUE ) ) AS value
FROM   TABLE( split_string( '1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448' ) );
```

**Output**:

```
     VALUE
----------
      1700 
      4000 
      3485 
      9684 
     20394 
     39448
```

**Query 3**:

```
WITH table_name( value ) AS (
  SELECT '1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  1 ) ) AS v1,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  2 ) ) AS v2,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  3 ) ) AS v3,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  4 ) ) AS v4,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  5 ) ) AS v5,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  6 ) ) AS v6,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  7 ) ) AS v7,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  8 ) ) AS v8,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1,  9 ) ) AS v9,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+', 1, 10 ) ) AS v10
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

```
        V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6         V7         V8         V9        V10
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1700       4000       3485       9684      20394      39448
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, splitting the string is not that difficult. Here is how it's done - but please do read my comment and respond.

In the query below, the first row just sets up test data; the actual query starts at line 2.

```
with test_data (input_str) as (select '1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448' from dual)
select 'multi_value' || level as name,
       regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as value
from test_data
connect by level <= regexp_count(input_str, ',') + 1
   and     prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME                 VALUE
----------------     -------------
multi_value1         1700
multi_value2         4000
multi_value3         3485
multi_value4         9684
multi_value5         20394
multi_value6         39448
```

Or - did you mean something like this?

**Output**:

```
MULTI_VALUE1 MULTI_VALUE2 MULTI_VALUE3 MULTI_VALUE4 MULTI_VALUE5 MULTI_VALUE6
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
        1700         4000         3485         9684        20394        39448
         120          300    100000000
```

**Query** to achieve this result:

```
with test_data (input_str) as (
            select '1700, 4000, 3485, 9684, 20394, 39448' from dual union all
            select '120, 300, 100000000' from dual)
select to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)) as multi_value1,
       to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 2, null, 1)) as multi_value2,
       to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 3, null, 1)) as multi_value3,
       to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 4, null, 1)) as multi_value4,
       to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 5, null, 1)) as multi_value5,
       to_number(regexp_substr(input_str, '\s?(\d*)(,|$)', 1, 6, null, 1)) as multi_value6
from test_data;
```

Comment: To explain the difference between my last Query and MT0's Query 3: His solution is simpler (see the match string in the regexp). My query will ONLY save a value if it is a number; MT0's solution allows a string like ax1330 between commas, it will save the value 1330. Also, in my solution I allow for nulls (if they exist for any reason) between two commas; MT0's solution ignores them, and simply consolidates all numbers to the left of the resulting row. Either approach may be correct, depending on the business requirements.